# Display one category and its suncategories

Tags: categories

I am using this code to filter posts. How can I modify to display only one category and its subcategories. Not all categories.

```
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
<?php
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0');
$select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
echo $select;
?>
    <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0');
```

put this:

```
$select = wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0&child_of=' . $ID_OF_PARENT_CATEGORY);
```

where $ID_OF_PARENT_CATEGORY is a variable holding the ID of parent category, from which you want to show the children.

## Showing parent

That category WON'T show. To show it, you must do some greater hack (here I'll show you only thing that I can think right now), since there are no argument like `include`, so that you can just include it.

You can show categories that are PARENT and it's siblings, so, you will show children of PARENT's parent. That means that you will put in args 'show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&orderby=name&echo=0&child_of='.$ID_OF_GRANDPARENT.'&exclude='.implode(',', ARRAY_OF_PARENTS_SIBLINGS)

[Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_dropdown_categories#Parameters)

Comment: Glad to help. :)